# Google My Maps embed - expand layer filter

Tags: google-maps

I'm embedding a Google "My Maps" like this one: http://borgensystems.com/contact-us/. In the top left corner, there's an expandable filter to turn layers off and on and click on them.

Is there a way to expand this by default on page load?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google does not expose anything to control the visibility of the Legend.
Via details see https://support.google.com/maps/forum/AAAAQuUrST8HvcYeJ1BIuQ/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/maps/HvcYeJ1BIuQ